# Laravel Eloquent enquiry

Tags: laravel-5

```
Customer::on($this->connection)->where('customer_id', $customer_id)->first()->name;
```

In this eloquent writting style is this mean to only return name on Customer table?
Sorry new to laravel and asking these newbie question.

Comment: try `echo` it whats the result

Comment: Yes, this code will direct access the `name` property of the returned single model instance if it is not null. This is same to `Customer::on($this->connection)->find($customer_id)->name`.